# Own password manager. How to store passwords

Tags: passwords, password-management, gnupg, node.js

I want to play a little bit and create my own little password manager (with gpg) in node.js

My question is how I should keep those passwords:

- In one encrypted file (let's say in json format),
- Separate file for every entry and all files keep in hidden directory. Filenames will be eg. stackoverlow@username and inside will be all necessary credentials with additional data.

What do you think? Maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: In order to answer this question we would need to know more about your threat model. Where do you host the password manager? On your own device or on a server? How much control have you over the server / the device? Are you the only one who has unsupervised physical access? Do you run untrusted software on it?

Comment: Also, how important are your passwords? Throwaway accounts on websites forcing registration for no reason? Your Facebook acount? Your online banking credentials? Your company server root password? Nuclear launch codes?

Comment: Security solutions exist to counter *threats*. Until you define the threats, it is impossible to assess a solution (unless the assessor applies their own threat models)

Comment: But why JSON? It's a hard format to look up info in. Why not sqlite or a similar database?

Comment: @Philipp I want to host it on my own device. I'm the only person who has access to my laptop. I want to store passwords to email accounts and services like facebook. I don't want to store passwords for crucial services like bank accounts on it.

Comment: @vidarlo I'm not decided about data format yet. If you recommend something else tell me about it.

Answer (score 2):

Both approaches have been used in many password managers. Neither of them are, strictly speaking, more secure than the other, it's just that they both have different security model, leading to different solutions and different trade offs.

Most password managers stores all data in one encrypted file. This is the default approach most password manager use. This has the advantage of being simpler and possibly slightly more secure but less flexible.

The approach where you store every password in different GPG files have been used in [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/). This had the advantage/weakness that the password file names are stored unencrypted, which allows many operations without needing to unlock the entire password store, you also have the flexibility of storing different passwords with different keys, or to share parts of your password directory.